# Allow HTML in Html.ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.listboxfor

How can I use HTML within a `@Html.ListBoxFor(i => i.Ids, i.Items)` to format each list item separately?

The text property of the `SelectListItem` has usually just text. But now I have to prepend an Icon with `new SelectListItem { Text = "<i class \"fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-user\"></i> Some Text" }`.

But ASP.NET MVC escapes me the string always. Is there already an implementation of a helper method with allows raw strings?

Comment: You can't. `ListBoxFor` merely generates a `<select multiple>` element, and that particular HTML control does not allow HTML. It's actually not even rendered by the browser; it's what's know as an "OS control", which is to say that the browser will use the native OS implmentation of a "select box". In other words, you have very little control whatsoever over what shows up. When you see "select boxes" with HTML inside, those are actually faked and are generated by JavaScript and use JavaScript to update the actual real select control behind the scenes.

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using bootstrap with the select2 plugin. After the view is rendered it's not a problem to replace a specific placeholder with an icon. But I don't like Java Script if it's possible without it. The only problem is that MVC escapes the HTML instead of raw output.

Comment: Well, the Select2 plugin will let you do exactly what you want, but notice in the example that it adds the HTML via JavaScript. There's no way to do this without JavaScript. Period.